# How to loop each line one by one in a txt file to display content in webbrowser using javascript after every 5sec

Tags: javascript, html

So, The thing is i made a code which displays the whole content of the .txt file but i need each line pop up on the web browser stay for 5 sec dissappear and the next line is popped up and this is looped.
And nly simple javascript is required.

```
<h1>
    Read File Using JavaScript
</h1>

<!-- Print as plain text -->
<h2>
    Plain Text:
</h2>
<pre id="contents"></pre>

<!-- Print as an array -->
<h2>
    Array Format:
</h2>
<pre id="hello-world-array"></pre>

<h2>
    Array Format (Shuffled):
</h2>
<pre id="hello-world-shuffle"></pre>

<input type="file" id="filechoice" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function shuffle(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle.
        while (currentIndex != 0) {

            // Pick a remaining element.
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex--;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
                array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
        }

        return array;
    }

    document.getElementById('filechoice').addEventListener('change',
        window.onload = function () {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function () {
                document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.result;
                const fileContentArray = this.result.split('\r\n'); // r n new line read
                document.getElementById('hello-world-array').textContent = JSON.stringify(fileContentArray, null, 2);
                document.getElementById('hello-world-shuffle').textContent = JSON.stringify(shuffle(fileContentArray), null, 2);
            };
            fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
            document.getElementById('hello-world-shuffle').textContent = JSON.stringify(shuffle(fileContentArray), null, 2);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try using `setInterval()` ?

Comment: i tried and ill send the new code

Comment: help me write the code please